# How to Format phone number like 999-999-9999x1234567890 to 999-999-9999x12345 in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

If there is **x** in the given phone number, then after truncating there won't be more than 5 digits after **x**.

If there is no **x** in the phone number, then after truncating it will same

Here is the possible situations

```
999-999-9999x1234567890  => 999-999-9999x12345
123-456-9999x123         => 123-456-9999x123   (no change)
999-999-9999             => 999-999-9999   (no change)
123456789                => 123456789   (no change)
999-1234567892           => 999-1234567892   (no change)
```

How can I achieve this in oracle SQL using regexp_substr or any other methods

Comment: [hhow-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (quick) simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE INSTR(value, 'x')
       WHEN 0
       THEN value
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, 'x') + 5)
       END AS shortened_value
FROM   table_name;
```

or (slower) regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '(x.{5}).+$', '\1')
         AS shortened_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '99-999-9999x1234567890' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123-456-9999x123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '999-999-9999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '999-1234567892' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | VALUE | SHORTENED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 99-999-9999x1234567890 | 99-999-9999x12345 |
> | 123-456-9999x123 | 123-456-9999x123 |
> | 999-999-9999 | 999-999-9999 |
> | 123456789 | 123456789 |
> | 999-1234567892 | 999-1234567892 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d84c8db10fb3faeb8d5c3da020f22d45)*